# Silverlight DataPager control loses first/last buttons

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datapager

I'm using the DataPager control in XAML as follows:

```
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <data:DataPager Grid.Column="1"
       Source="{Binding PagedCollection, ElementName=ucPagingControl}"
       PageSize="{Binding PagedCollection.PageSize, ElementName=ucPagingControl}" 
       AutoEllipsis="True" 
       DisplayMode="FirstLastPreviousNextNumeric" />
```

and all displays well for the first 99 pages

[image]

However, after page 100 I lose the first/last button graphics

[image]

Any ideas why or how to change the number of pages displayed to recover the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the fix was in the Grid definition.  The following works:

```
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: I was just going to suggest that it looks like the column's not wide enough to display all the control.